# Typescript: Control routing path at runtime

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I'm looking to setup the routing path during load/runtime (not component with LoadChildren)
I've come across a lot of similar post, but not quite what I think I'm looking for.

I'm building a generic CMS system for product reviews and want a single system to work for all different products.

Routing setup example:

```
const routes: Routes = [
   { path: '',  redirectTo: '/bread-machines/reviews/2020', pathMatch: 'full' },
   { pah: 'bread-machines/reviews/2020' , component: ProductReviewsComponent},
   { path: 'bread-machines/reviews/2020/:id' , component: ProductDetailComponent },
```

];

this works fine, but I want to be able to change the paths at runtime/load. The components will remain the same, but the path needs to be dynamic (bread-machines needs to be able to change to toaster).

Comment: The angular router is well documented: https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: R. Richards. I've been through that before (all 20k lines) and just not sure what example is applicable to the problem I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

> if you want routing at ts use this

```js
 constructor( private router: Router){}
 
 click()
   {
     this.router.navigate(['/path/path']);
   }
```

```html
> if you want routing at html please use this model

    <button mat-button  routerLink="/path/path" >
               ADD EMAIL</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should configure parameterized routes:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    children: [
      { path: ":category", component: YearComponent, },
      { path: ':category/reviews/:year', component: ProductReviewsComponent },
      { path: ':category/reviews/:year/:id', component: ProductDetailComponent }
    ]
  },
  { path: "**", component: PageNotFoundComponent },
];
```

Check this demo I made based on your example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6jhye5

Please, ask if you have any doubts regarding the demo or the proposed solution.

Answer (score -1):

You need  to use

```
router.config
```

inside a constructor.

Comment: I don't exactly know what to try.
My concern is that either I'm not searching for a solution correctly or what I'm trying to do is not a viable solution.
Because I cannot find a single code snippet that explains how to load a route for either bread-machine or toaster at load/runtime.

Answer (score -1):

export class AppRoutingModule {

constructor(private router: Router) { 
    router.config.push({ path: 'bread-machines/reviews/2020/:id' , component: ProductDetailComponent });

}
}

Comment: What is this? An answer?